# How can I group Land Cover Classification into urban vs rural areas and summarize Land Surface Temperature for each class in python?

Tags: land-cover, resampling, nlcd, land-surface-temperature, goes-16

I have NLCD land cover classifications from an `.img` file as follow:

[image: Land Cover Classification Legend]

I would like to somehow reclassify these into Urban or Rural by taking all developed as urban and the rest, minus water as rural.

How can I do that?

Next I would calculate Land Surface Temperature(LST) for each pixel belonging to those new groups, rural/urban. LST data is from GOES-16 and I have it gridded same as nlcd data on a 0.01 x 0.01 grid.

The end goal is to see if urban areas has high LST than rural, in other words evaluating Urban Heat Island.